# SQLITE glob search with negation

Tags: sql, sqlite

Hello I'm doing this query to find all fields containing numbers:

```
SELECT text FROM note WHERE note glob '*[0-9]*'
```

I would like to negate results where the number is contained in a word starting with '@'. 
Here is some sample data. I would like to get the first two and ignore the last one.

```
"@julianjones has 125 apples" 
"@brianadams1 has 135 oranges"
"@adamsmith123 disconnected"
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: Thanks @forpas I've added some more info.

Comment: What if the number is part of a word: `brianadams1 disconnected`. Do you want it in the results?

Comment: That should be included as it doesn't contain the '@'. Thanks. @forpas

Comment: Yes but the content is free typed so it could say "@brianadams1 has135 oranges" without a space for example. @forpas

Comment: I can't see any pattern to search for in this case.